# turn off abbrev-mode in Emacs minibuffer?

Tags: emacs, ido, minibuffer

I use abbrev-mode, smex, and ido-mode. How do I turn off abbrev-mode in the minibuffer for when I smex a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code disables abbrev when you enter the minibuffer, then enables it again when you leave it.

```
(defun conditionally-disable-abbrev ()
  ""
  (if (string-match "smex-" (format "%s" this-command))
      (abbrev-mode -1)))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'conditionally-disable-abbrev)
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode 1)))
```

Added the fix by juanleon.

Comment: Mmmm, a lambda is getting in your way.  You can fix that by changing the `if` line in that function to `(if (string-match "smex-" (format "%s" this-command))`.

Comment: Great! And how do I turn off abbrev-mode for ido-mode? When I try to save a file, for instance, it's still expanding my abbrevs in the filenames.

Comment: Same logic, just replace smex with ido. You can also just remove the if line and have it always disabled in the minibuffer.